# Bitbucket API returns 'Bad request' when using python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, bitbucket-api

I want to make a request to Bitbucket API to create repository.
The following curl works:

```
curl -v -X POST -d '{"scm": "git", "is_private": "true", "fork_policy": "no_forks", "project": {"key": "MARS"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"  https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myteam/test -u <user-name>
```

So I tried the same in python using requests:

```
data = {'scm': 'git', 'is_private': 'true', 'fork_policy': 'no_forks', 'project': {'key': 'MARS'}}
auth=(user, password)
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
url = "https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/myteam/test"
res = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, auth=auth)
```

but the `res` returns 'Bad request' (400). why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is evident from your `curl` request that Bitbucket is accepting JSON-Encoded POST data.
Sending data using `requests`as form-encoded data results in a HTTP Error 400 Bad request.

In order to send as JSON-Encoded POST data, use:

```
requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers, auth=auth)
```

#### Reference:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests